# Detail: Invalid response from http://simca.tech/.well-known/acme-challenge/Kmjz6pdfz91ubRRrE_AL-qQ5Z-1FB7vfM3WSt6xuul8

Tags: ssl, nginx

i'm trying of get a ssl with let's encrypt, i have nginx and nodejs but when i type this comand "sudo certbot --nginx -d simca.tech" appear this:

```
Failed authorization procedure. simca.tech (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://simca.tech/.well-known/acme-challenge/Kmjz6pdfz91ubRRrE_AL-qQ5Z-1FB7vfM3WSt6xuul8 [104.248.66.200]: "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title>Cliente</title>\n  <base href=\"/\">\n\n  <meta name=\"viewp"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: simca.tech
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://simca.tech/.well-known/acme-challenge/Kmjz6pdfz91ubRRrE_AL-qQ5Z-1FB7vfM3WSt6xuul8
   [103.xxx.65.xxx]: "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n
   <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n  <title>Cliente</title>\n  <base
   href=\"/\">\n\n  <meta name=\"viewp"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```